# Unable to instantiate chaincode in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

**Hi, I am working on balance-transfer in fabric-sample with hyperledger fabric in blockchain. I am unable to instantiate chaincode , getting promise is rejected**

[image]

Comment: Which version of Fabric are you using?

Comment: fabric 1.0v I am using

Comment: For some reason, you are not able to pull from Docker hub.
Can you run "docker pull hyperledger/fabric-baseos:x86_64-0.4.2" ?

Comment: even I am unable to pull image also getting the below error                                   Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/hyperledger/fabric-baseos/manifests/x86_64-0.4.2: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Ahyperledger%2Ffabric-baseos%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Comment: this is network issue only. I tried same thing in different network, in that case it's worked properly without any fail

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem before. And the problem is like your problem. it's when I exec ./testAPI.sh occur. I solve the problem after I add the chaincode in the github.com/example_cc/go/ directory.I think you can have a try.